# Displays a dialog when taking a picture of the screen

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I need to block a screen capture and display a dialog box for the user when trying to capture a screenshot.
Here I can only block the user from taking a picture of the screen but it is difficult to access the user when taking a picture of the screen.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
     android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,  
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

How do I show a dialog box containing a message to the user when taking a picture of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is nothing in Android to allow you to detect a screenshot, let alone display alternative content. Your options are to block portions of your UI using `FLAG_SECURE` (as noted in your question) or not.

Comment: In the application of the electronic market "WISH"
When a screenshot is taken, a dialog box appears showing the link of the shot
Can not we create a similar code?

Comment: @s-eivi: That is a different scenario than what your question asks. They are attempting to find out about a screenshot *after* it has been taken; your question is for finding out about a screenshot *before* it has been taken. Also, most likely, they are monitoring `MediaStore` or a particular directory on the filesystem and trying to guess which ones are screenshots, which ignores the possibility of screenshots that do not result in those sorts of changes that they can detect.